# Ajax Php Delete a file from server

Tags: php, ajax, file, delete-file

I can not seem to figure out what I'm missing could you all give me some help?

```js
function deleteFile(file){

var file = encodeURIComponent(file);


if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
document.getElementById("media").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.bennettauto.biz/file-tree-hr/delete.php?file=\""+file, true);
xmlhttp.send();
alert(clicked);
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div id='TrashFile'><a href="javascript:void(0)"onClick='deleteFile(<? echo $deletefile; ?>);'><img src='http://www.bennettauto.biz/images/tool_trash.gif'></a></div>
```

delete.php:

```
<?php
    // I save the file sources from the URL what was sent by AJAX to these variables.
    $file = $_GET['file'];


    function deleteFiles($id){
        // If is a file then delete the file.
        if(is_file($id)){
            return unlink($id);
        // Else show error.
        } else {
            echo $id . " is not a file, or there is a problem with it.<br />" ; 
        }
    }

    if(isset($file)){
        deleteFiles($file);
    }


 ?>
```

The onClick function does not seem to be calling delete.php, there is something I'm missing but I can't see what.

Comment: i so hope you have more code on the server side

this is extremly dangerous. So anyone could delete every file which is writeable by the server.

Comment: Look at the generated JavaScript. Do you understand why the generated JavaScript does not work? Do you understand why the PHP is generating that JavaScript? You should be seeking an answer to one of those questions rather then presenting us with the extreme ends.

Comment: Don't use GET requests to delete things. GET requests are supposed to be SAFE.

Comment: This is on a internal website, it is not open to the public

Comment: Took a different route without ajax, thanks for the comments!

Comment: ready state may be "complete" instead of 4. If you have possibility to use jQuery, it will save you a lot of general code... `$.ajax({ type: "get", url: ".../delete.php", data: { file: "..." }, success: function(res) {document.getElementById("media").innerHTML=res; } });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://www.bennettauto.biz/file-tree-hr/delete.php?file=\""+file, true);

What's that `\"` doing there? I don't see a matching quotation mark for that. When sending info using GET you should not include quotation marks.

And on a more general note, this is very dangerous code, I'm assuming that this is for an Admin but I don't see any authorization checks in delete.php. At least check if the user is logged in etc.